# Align content with the bottom of a table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

My sense is that I am missing something basic, but here goes:

I have a `\tabular` object, and on the same line as it ends, I wish to put a `\Box`

If I create a dummy column to store the `\Box` then the table is not wide enough (I want the box at the end of the line)

If I use `\hfill $\Box$` after the end of the table (if there is a manual newline after the table, else it vertically centers it on the right which is also not what I want) it left justifies as it is the only thing on the line. If I use `test  \hfill $\Box$` I get what I want (well, its really one line down too far, but thats OK) but with a pesky `test` at the beginning of the line (as an aside, this seems to be a common issue with me, so if there is a way to have a "dummy" (not visible, has no other impact on the document) character that would do as well).

How can I get what I am looking for?

Comment: The "dummy" object that you are looking for can be `\mbox{}` or `\null`.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina this works and I will accept it, but I would prefer a cleaner way (and on the same line as the end of the table)

Comment: I was not proposing using `\mbox{}` or `\null` as part of the solution; I was only mentioning that this is the standard "dummy" object you were asking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `[b]` optional argument for `tabular`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}[b]{|cc|}
text & text \\
text & text \\
text & text \\
\end{tabular}\hfill$\Box$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using `[t]`, the top line of the table is aligned with the baseline of the current external line of text; using `[b]`, the bottom line of the table is aligned with the external baseline; with `[c]` (or with no positioning argument given), the table is centered on the external baseline.

Comment: For some reason it come it comes out vertically centered on my table (http://snag.gy/8VBNP.jpg for an example of what it looks like on my table)

Comment: @soandos Did you use the `[b]` alignment specifier I used in my example for `tabular`?

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks. What does it do?

Comment: @soandos `[b]` vertically aligns the table at the bottom, `[t]` aligns it at the top and `[c]` (default) at the center.